# Rails Client side validation not passing true even after selecting jquery datepicker

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, client-side-validation

In my application I have implemented jquery datepicker as well as rails client side validations. But even after I select the dates, I get the error as "can't be blank" and the form doesn't gets submitted.. How do I pass the validation after selecting a date.

Please find my code for datepicker below.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){  
$('#project_start_date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",onSelect: function(selected) {

$("#project_end_date").datepicker("option","minDate", selected)

}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As described on the [Client Side Validations wiki](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/wiki/jQuery-Plugins), you can add this option to make jQueryUI DatePicker compatible with Client Side Validations:

```
onClose: function(dateText, inst) { $(inst.input).change().focusout(); }
```

In your example:

```
$('#project_start_date').datepicker({
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
  onSelect: function(selected) { $("#project_end_date").datepicker("option","minDate", selected) },
  onClose: function(dateText, inst) { $(inst.input).change().focusout(); }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that the validation is triggered when focus is out... as a workaround you can trigger the focus events manually after the datapicker is closed

```
$('#project_start_date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",onSelect: function(selected) {

$("#project_end_date").datepicker("option","minDate", selected)

}, onClose: function(){
      //workaround to trigger javascript validation
      $(this).focusout();
}
});
```